# Stock analysis using quantmod in r

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to run a script each day to analyse today's prices against stocks selected some time ago from a screener.

To that end I have loaded a csv file with the data, one column of which is titled "Ticker", and cleaned it to have the stocks I'm interested in, for instance Apple, Google and Microsoft.

Then I create a vector with this code:

```
tickers <- paste(shQuote(data$Ticker), collapse = ", ")
```

When I try to run quantmod to pull the prices down with this:

```
today <- getQuote(tickers)
```

I get an error in download but if I code it like this:

```
today <- getQuote(c("AAPL", "GOOG", "MSFT")
```

it pulls the detail down fine and I can continue.

Since there are over 80 stocks most days, I wanted to automate it but clearly I am doing something wrong - any ideas?

Comment: What does `data$Ticker` look like?  Can you define a short dataframe for a reproducible example?

Comment: Get your all stocks in a vector,then apply a for loop and store all the details in a list. Convert it to dataframe with Date as a row index and stocks as a columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you simply need to call
`getQuote(data$Ticker)`.
If `data$Ticker` is a `factor`, then just cast it as a character.  That is,
`getQuote(as.character(data$Ticker))`.
I hope this helps!

Comment: You were absolutely right about having to cast it as a character - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need unique stock codes?

```
tickers <- paste(unique(shQuote(data$Ticker)), collapse = ", ")
```